# Guile scheme - quoted period?

Tags: scheme, guile

What does the following Guile scheme code do?

```
(eq? y '.)
(cons x '.)
```

The code is not valid in MzScheme, is there a portable equivalent across scheme implementations?

I am trying to port this code written by someone else. Guile seems to respond to '. with #{.}#, but I'm not sure what it means or how to do this in another scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it seems that '. is valid syntax for (string->symbol ".") in Guile, whereas MzScheme at least requires |.| for the period as a symbol.

Answer (score 1):

`#{.}#` is Guile specific way to define the symbol contains some delimiters of Scheme.
http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Symbol-Read-Syntax.html

For other Scheme dialect, there should be another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm surprised any Scheme system will accept a dot symbol at all.  My advice is to use another symbol as (I'm sure you're aware) the dot is a shorthand to represent a pair, and even if you can find a Scheme that will take your code you will likely confuse anyone that has the unfortunate task of actually reading your code.

Comment: Symbols can contain _any_ sequence of characters that would be valid in a string, and you can intern any string into a symbol by using `string->symbol`. However, the symbols you can write as bare tokens, without using pipe or backslash escaping, is a rather smaller subset.